# Oracle multiple transactions in declare-begin-end statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose we have two tables that are the following:

```
             Parent
╔════╦════════╦═════════════════╗
║ ID ║  Name  ║      Email      ║
╠════╬════════╬═════════════════╣
║  1 ║ George ║ george@test.com ║
║  2 ║ Peter  ║ peter@test.com  ║
╚════╩════════╩═════════════════╝

             Child
╔════════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ CUSTID ║   City   ║    Road     ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║      1 ║ London   ║ Queens Road ║
║      1 ║ Athens   ║ Makedonias  ║
║      2 ║ New York ║ 24th Steet  ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

and the `child.custid` has a constrain on `parent.id`.

What I want to do is add data to the table by using a declare-begin-end statement but what I get is a constrain error. The statement I use is the following:

```
declare
  varCustId parent.id%type;
  varCustName parent.name%type := 'John';
  varCustEmail parent.email%type := 'john@test.com';
begin
  select max(id)+1 int varCustId from parent;
  insert into parent(id,name,email) values(varCustId,varCustName,varCustEmail);
  -- I tried adding a 'commit;' here but it didn't make any difference
  insert into child(custid,city,road) values(varCustId, 'Thessaloniki', 'Mpotsari');
end;
```

The message I get exactly is `integrity constraint (...) violated - parent key not found`.

Is something like this possible without having to disable/drop the constrain and enable/create it again?

Of course this is a very simplified version of the tables and statement I use.

Comment: Is it possible you have another constraint?

Comment: You don't have to commit first insert to not getting error on second insert. All statements is executing in same transaction. Probably you have facing another constraint or custid is not foreign field of parent table id field.

Comment: The message I get exactly is `integrity constraint (...) violated - parent key not found`.
I do have another constrain but those are fulfilled since the values I add for those columns preexist. Like for example having a table with towns and using those towns in the insertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner, 
       c.r_owner, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
  FROM all_cons_columns a
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                           AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
 WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
   AND a.table_name = 'CHILDTABLE';
```

Use the above query to find the *referential* constraints (with column names been referred) over your table!

Comment: Seems I had an extra constrain I missed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the idea to use SELECT max(id)+1 will not work in multitransaction environment. You should use sequence instead. Also, the scenario when you put data into parent table first and in child table next is absolutely correct - if we talk of foreign key constraint.
You should not experience problems:

```
SQL> create table parent (id int primary key
  2  , name varchar2(20)
  3  , email varchar2(40)
  4  )
  5  /

SQL> create table child (custid int references parent(id)
  2  ,city varchar2(40)
  3  ,road varchar2(40)
  4  )
  5  /

SQL> create sequence seq_test
  2  /

SQL> declare
  2    varCustId parent.id%type;
  3    varCustName parent.name%type := 'John';
  4    varCustEmail parent.email%type := 'john@test.com';
  5  begin
  6    insert into parent(id,name,email) values(seq_test.nextval,varCustName,varCustEmail)
  7    returning id into varCustId;
  8    insert into child(custid,city,road) values(varCustId, 'Thessaloniki', 'Mpotsari');
  9  end;
 10  /

SQL> select * from parent;

        ID NAME                 EMAIL                                           
---------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------        
         1 John                 john@test.com                                   

SQL> select * from child
  2  /

    CUSTID CITY                                                                 
---------- ----------------------------------------                             
ROAD                                                                            
----------------------------------------                                        
         1 Thessaloniki                                                         
Mpotsari
```

The problem may occur if you try to insert into child table first. Then one of the solution is the deferrable constraint (in case you can't guarantee certain order of inserts):

```
SQL> declare
  2    varCustId parent.id%type;
  3    varCustName parent.name%type := 'John';
  4    varCustEmail parent.email%type := 'john@test.com';
  5  begin
  6    insert into child(custid,city,road) values(seq_test.nextval, 'Thessaloniki', 'Mpotsari')
  7    returning custid into varCustId;
  8    insert into parent(id,name,email) values(varCustId,varCustName,varCustEmail);
  9  end;
 10  /
declare
...
ORA-02291: integrity constraint constraint (ODH.SYS_C00308311) - parent key not found 
..

SQL> alter table child drop constraint sys_c00308311;


SQL> truncate table child;


SQL> truncate table parent;


SQL> alter table child add constraint child_fk foreign key (custid)
  2  references parent(id) deferrable initially deferred;

Таблица изменена.

SQL> declare
  2    varCustId parent.id%type;
  3    varCustName parent.name%type := 'John';
  4    varCustEmail parent.email%type := 'john@test.com';
  5  begin
  6    insert into child(custid,city,road) values(seq_test.nextval, 'Thessaloniki', 'Mpotsari')
  7    returning custid into varCustId;
  8    insert into parent(id,name,email) values(varCustId,varCustName,varCustEmail);
  9  end;
 10  /

SQL> commit;


SQL> select * from parent;

        ID NAME                 EMAIL                                           
---------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------        
         3 John                 john@test.com                                   

SQL> select * from child;

    CUSTID CITY                                                                 
---------- ----------------------------------------                             
ROAD                                                                            
----------------------------------------                                        
         3 Thessaloniki                                                         
Mpotsari
```